# Why do particles don't react with physics once the hit the "floor"

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I'm trying to make some circular-shaped confetti fall onto the ground using particles, but the "confetti" just lands with the same orientation as how it was dropped and does not react with real physics. Does anyone know how to fix that?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can give any physics to the particles, or maybe with Geometry Nodes?